# Incomplete ionization in a depletion region

Tags: semiconductor-physics

The expression for a non-degenerate depletion region width in a pn junction is expressed as a function of Nd and Na, and Vbi, under the assumption of complete ionization of all acceptons and dopants.
If we have incomplete ionization, there are well known expressions for the Na-/Na and Nd+/Nd ratios in the bulk as a function of doping energy distance from the fermi level...ie Ef-Ed and Ea-Ef.  However if we form a junction, is it always assumed that the full ionization will be satisfied in the depletion region before carriers are swept out? I.e., does the field developed also cause field ionization of those non-ionized dopants?
Bottom line:  Can I use Na and Nd in the depletion width expression, regardless of ionization energy of dopants, or must I use the ionized fractions if the energy is much higher than kT?

Thanks!

Comment: Field ionization? No. Continual sweeping out of any generated carriers? Yes. So, given time, non-ionized dopants will get ionized. Then, how many (electrons/holes) are available to "un-ionize" the dopants?

Comment: My gut is that in steady state, the ionization rate per unit time will be balanced by an ionized center retrapping rate. In which case, if I only had X% ionization due to a large ionization energy, I should use that X*Na or X*Nd of dopants in the depletion width calculation.

Comment: Where are the free carriers for retrapping coming from? Free carriers are swept out of the depletion region by the built-in fields.

Comment: Diffusion from the quasi-static regions, balancing the continual ionization...